# What are other methods to evaluate $\int_0^1 \sqrt{-\ln x} \ \mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

$$\int_0^1 \sqrt{-\ln x} dx$$
**I'm looking for alternative methods  to what I already know (method I have used below) to evaluate this Integral.**
$$y=-\ln x$$

$$\bbox[8pt, border:1pt solid crimson]{e^y=e^{-\ln x}=e^{\ln\frac{1}{x}}=\frac{1}{x}}$$

$$\color{#008080}{dx= -\frac{dy}{e^y}}$$

$$\int_0^1  \sqrt{-\ln x} dx=\int_{\infty}^0 \sqrt{y} \left(-\frac{dy}{e^y}\right)=\int_0^{\infty} e^{-y} y^{\frac{1}{2}}dy=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)!$$

$$\bbox[8pt, border:1pt solid crimson]{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)!=\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\pi}}$$

$$\Large{\color{crimson}{\int_0^1 \sqrt{-\ln x} dx=\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\pi}}}$$

Comment: Do you mean different methods completely, or are different substitutions also ok? You could solve it with $-\ln x = y^2$ as well for instance.

Comment: @Slugger Different Substitutions too :) Il be glad to receive as many answers as possible :)

Comment: @TheArtist in the integral you should have $y^{+\frac{1}{2}}$.

Comment: @alexjo oops a typo :) thanks for spotting it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, there are essentially two ways for proving that $\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\sqrt{\pi}$.

The first way is to use integration by parts, leading to $\Gamma(z+1)=z\Gamma(z)$, in order to relate $\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$ to the Wallis product. The latter can be computed by exploiting the Weierstrass product for the sine function:
$$\frac{\sin z}{z}=\prod_{n=1}^{+\infty}\left(1-\frac{z^2}{\pi^2n^2}\right)$$
by evaluating it in $z=\frac{\pi}{2}$. The duplication formula for the $\Gamma$ function follows from this approach.

The second way is to use some substitutions in order to relate $\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$ to the gaussian integral
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-x^2}\,dx$$
that can be evaluated through Fubini's theorem and polar coordinates.

Comment: (+1) Oh I see, I used the first way. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 10):

*Here's slightly different approach*

We have 
$$\mathcal I=\int_0^1 \sqrt{-\ln x} \mathrm dx=\int_0^1 \left[\ln\frac1 x\right]^{1/2} \mathrm dx$$
By using IBP
$$\left[\ln\frac1 x\right]^{1/2}=u\iff\mathrm du= -\frac 1{2x}\left[\ln\frac1 x\right]^{-1/2}\mathrm dx$$

$$\mathrm dx=\mathrm dv\iff x=v$$

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal I
&=x\left[\ln\frac1 x\right]^{1/2}\Bigg\rvert_0^1+ \frac 1{2}\int_0^1\left[\ln\frac1 x\right]^{-1/2}\mathrm dx\\
&=\frac 1{2}\int_0^1\left[\ln\frac1 x\right]^{-1/2}\mathrm dx\\
\end{align}$$
Now by substututing
$$t^2=\ln\frac1x\implies e^{-t^2}=x\iff \mathrm dx=-2te^{-t^2}\mathrm dt$$
We get
$$\mathcal I=\int _0^\infty e^{-t^2}\mathrm dt=\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2}$$
Hence,

> $$\int_0^1 \sqrt{-\ln x} \mathrm dx=\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2}$$

Answer (score 4):

Similar to what Iuʇǝƃɹɐʇoɹ did, let $u=\sqrt{-\ln x}$. Then $x=e^{-u^2}$ and hence
$$ \int_0^1\sqrt{-\ln x}dx=-\int_0^\infty ud(e^{-u^2})=-ue^{-u^2}|_0^\infty+\int_0^\infty e^{-u^2}du=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}. $$

Answer (score 3):

> Here are two more variations of the theme. According to OPs presentation and the characterisation of @JackDAurizio the essential point is to show the identity
>
> $$\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\sqrt{\pi}$$

The first variant is based upon the *beta integral* in combination with a substitution to obtain the identity.

The second one is much more exciting. It's not the calculation itself which is routine work, but the *new concept* based upon **periods** introduced at the end of the last millennium.

> **1. Variant:** Beta integral with substitution

Following *[Special functions](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521789885)* by G.E. Andrews, R. Askey and R. Roy we recall the definition of the *beta-integral*

\begin{align*}
B(x,y)=\int_0^{1}t^{x-1}(1-t)^{y-1}dt\qquad\qquad \operatorname{Re} x>0,\operatorname{Re} y>0
\end{align*}

and the well known identity

\begin{align*}
B(x,y)=\frac{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}
\end{align*}

> This symmetry of the beta integral gives rise to the substitution  $t=\sin^2\theta$. We obtain
>
> \begin{align*}
> B(x,y)=2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^{2x-1}\theta\cos^{2y-1}\theta d\theta=\frac{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}
> \end{align*}
>
> Put $x=\frac{1}{2},y=\frac{1}{2}$, to get
>
> \begin{align*}
> B\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)=2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}d\theta=\pi=\frac{\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})^2}{\Gamma(1)}
> \end{align*}
>
> and $\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\sqrt{\pi}$ follows.

Another substitution of the beta integral will be convenient in the next variant.

> **Variant 2:** $\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$ and $\sqrt{\pi}$ are **periods** forming an *accessible identity*
>
> The definition of periods below and the proof is based upon the fascinating introductory *[survey paper about periods](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/kontzagi.pdf)* by M. Kontsevich and D. Zagier.

**Periods** are defined as complex numbers whose real and imaginary parts are values of absolutely convergent integrals of *rational functions* with *rational coefficient* over domains in $\mathbb{R}^n$ given by polynomial inequalities with *rational coefficients*.

The set of periods is therefore a *countable* subset of the complex numbers. It contains the algebraic numbers, but also many of famous transcendental constants. One can also replace rational functions with *algebraic functions* and rational coefficient with *algebraic coefficient* without changing the set of numbers $\mathcal{P}$.

> In order to show the identity $\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\sqrt{\pi}$ we first have to show according to Kontsevich's and Zagiers paper that both $\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$ and $\sqrt{\pi}$ are *periods* and that they form a so-called *accessible identity*.
>
> **First step of the proof:** $\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$ and $\pi$ are periods
>
> There are a lot of different proper representations of $\pi$ showing that this constant is a period. In the referred paper above following expressions (besides others) of $\pi$ are stated:
>
> \begin{align*}
> \pi= \iint \limits_{x^2+y^2\leq 1}dxdy=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{dt}{1+t^2}=\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
>
> showing that *$\pi$ is a period*. According to the paper values of the *gamma function*
>   $$\Gamma(s)=\int_{0}^{\infty}t^{s-1}e^{-t}dt$$
>   at rational values of the argument $s$ are closely related to periods:
>   $$\Gamma(p/q)^q\in \mathcal{P}\qquad\qquad (p,q\in\mathbf{N}).$$
>   This follows from the repesentation of $\Gamma(p/q)^q$ as beta integral. Putting $p=1$ and $q=2$ it follows that $\Gamma(1/2)^2$ is a period.
>
> We conclude: $\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$ is a period.

$$ $$

> **Second step:** $\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$ and $\sqrt{\pi}$ form an *accessible identity*.

An **accessible identity** between two periods $A$ and $B$ is given, if we can transform the integral representation of period $A$ by application of the three rules: *Additivity* (integrand and domain), *Change of variables* and *Newton-Leibniz formula* to the integral representation of period $B$.

This implies **equality** of the periods and the job is done.

> We again consider the beta integral and take the substitution $t=\frac{u-a}{b-a}$. We get
>   \begin{align*}
> \int_a^b(b-u)^{x-1}(u-a)^{y-1}du
> &=(b-a)^{x+y-1}B(x,y)\\
> &=(b-a)^{x+y-1}\frac{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}
> \end{align*}
>
> The special case $a=-1, b=1$ gives
>
> \begin{align*}
> \int_{-1}^{1}(1+t)^{x-1}(1-t)^{y-1}dt=2^{x+y-1}\frac{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}
> \end{align*}
>
> Put $x=y=\frac{1}{2}$ to get
>
> \begin{align*}
> \int_{-1}^{1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt=\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2=\pi\tag{2}
> \end{align*}
>
> The identities in (1) and (2) show that $\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$ and $\sqrt{\pi}$ form an accessible identity and  the claim $\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\sqrt{\pi}$ follows.